# ServiceStack - [Authenticate] attribute is called before request filters. Does not work with OrmLiteMultitenancyAuthRepository / OrmLiteCacheClient

Tags: servicestack

I have a multitenant application with a schema per tenant postgres database

The database contains the following schemas:

```
tenant_cf5f3518bd524c3797b884457b374e50
tenant_46255f07079046139f8c0f94290885cd
tenant_620ef0de80f74f95992742e8db4b153f
tenant_6d93b51d61ed4e33a5fb324845a83603
tenant_8e0fd300a3124de29a3070b89f3662ed
...
```

I set the `TenantId` on the `IRequest.Items` in an **async** request filter.

```
TenantIdFilter.cs
-----------------
var aHasTenant = dto as IHaveTenant;
if (aHasTenant == null) return;
if (hasTenant.TenantId == Guid.Empty)
{
    var error = DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(req, HttpError.BadRequest("Missing tenant id"));
    await res.WriteToResponse(req, error);
}
if (!req.GetSession().IsAuthenticated){
    var error = DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(req, HttpError.Unauthorized("Unauthorized"));
    await res.WriteToResponse(req, error);
    req.Items.Remove("TenantId")
}
req.Items.Add("TenantId", hasTenant.TenantId);

...

appHost.GlobalAsyncRequestFilters.Add(new TenantIdFilter().Invoke);
```

I've set up the `AppHost.GetDbConnection()` to retrieve the per-tenant connection. This all works well. I've set up the postgres connection string to include.

```
var connectionString = AppSettings.GetString('ConnectionString');
if (req.Items.ContainsKey("TenantId")){
  var tenantId = (Guid)req.Items["TenantId"];
  connectionString = connectionString + ';Search Path=tenant_{tenantId}'
}
return new OrmLiteDbConnectionFactory(connectionString).Open()
...
```

The problem arises when I use `[Authenticate]` attributes (I suspect the same would happen with roles/permissions attributes).

```
[Authenticate]
public class RestrictedDto : IReturnVoid {
}
```

**It seems that the `[Authenticate]` filter is called before any `GlobalRequestFilter`**. That means the `TenantId` will not be set on the `IRequest.Items`. And thus, the `GetDbConnection(IRequest request)` will retrieve an invalid `IDbConnection` (will not take the `TenantId` since it's not present yet).

When the `Authenticate` filter tries to retrieve the session info from the `ICacheClient`, the `ICacheClient` (`OrmLiteCacheClient`) retrieves the `DbConnection` from `AppHost.GetDbConnection()`. It then throws an error that the `cache_entry` table was not found.

I want the `TenantIdFilter.cs` to be ran before any `[Authenticate]` attribute. How can I do that?

Perhaps there is a method I could override in the `AppHost` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Authentication Attribute is a [Request Filter attribute](https://docs.servicestack.net/filter-attributes) which by design has the [lowest priority of all built-in attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/RequestFilterPriority.cs) to prevent unauthorized requests executing App logic.

You can resolve the tenant in your custom `GetDbConnection()` where the Request DTO will be available from `IRequest.Dto` property, e.g:

```
public override IDbConnection GetDbConnection(IRequest req = null)
{
    var tenantId = req?.Dto is IHaveTenant hasTenant ? hasTenant.TenantId : (Guid?) null;
}
```

Comment: My problem was with JWT tokens. I added a PopulateSessionFilter and PopulateTokenFilter to add and retrieve the TenantId from the token. I had a check in that TenantIdFilter.cs to verify if the session was authenticated, and had the TenantId set on it. (It was bad since it would only work theoretically with JWT/Cookies)

Basically, to get the DbConnection, I needed to check the MyCustomSession.TenantId. But to get the MyCustomSession.TenantId, I needed the DbConnection.

P.S. How would I throw an error in the GetDbConnection? Simply throw HttpError.BadRequest, or res.WriteErrorResponse?

Comment: @LudovicC You can throw an Exception as normal